# Passing data between WinForms forms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have made a secondary form in my project which can get data from the main form, and  should pass some out to the main form when a button is clicked.
here is the code:

**Add.cs:**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            main ma = new main();

                ma.optionType = "add";
                ma.optionName = txtName.Text;
                ma.optionURL = txtURL.Text;
                ma.optionInterval = "12";
                //What should I pass here?


            this.Close();
        }
```

**main.cs:**

```
  private string opt;// create a property
        public string optionType
        {
            get
            {
                return opt;
            }
            set
            {
                opt = value;
            }
        }
        private string opt2;// create a property
        public string optionName
        {
            get
            {
                return opt2;
            }
            set
            {
                opt2 = value;
            }
        }
        private string opt3;// create a property
        public string optionURL
        {
            get
            {
                return opt3;
            }
            set
            {
                opt3 = value;
            }
        }
        private string opt4;// create a property
        public string optionInterval
        {
            get
            {
                return opt4;
            }
            set
            {
                opt4 = value;
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I don't know when to try to fetch the data coming from add.cs after   button1 (in add.cs) was clicked. With what event should I check if the data came?

Comment: I you answered it yourself feel free to post an answer, it may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed it to this:
add.cs:

```
 public string optionType { get; set; }
 public string optionName { get; set; }
 public string optionURL { get; set; }
 public string optionInterval { get; set; }
 public int yCoord { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know about the changed value before closing the child form, a custom event will let you inform the parent form elegantly.

Here's a great tutorial on delegates and events in C#

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Once the child form is instantiated, the parent form would register to receive one or more custom events (as needed) from the child.

Another methodology is to pass a reference to the parent form into the child form so that the child can invoke a function or property of the parent to inform about the change.  However, that approach creates a tight coupling between the two forms and is discouraged.